# Get Line Highlighting (or at Least a Stack Trace) for noSuchMethod Exception Dart

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I'm using Dart Editor. When I accidently call a method on null, or trigger any other very common runtime error, I'd like the IDE to tell me where the exception came from. Instead it just tells me the name of the method, the arguments and the receiver of the call.

I end up having to step through the program from the entrypoint, see where it falls off, and then make a forensic guess of what might have thrown the exception.

Is there a setting that's wrong? I'm used to having my IDE take me right to the offending line, or getting a stacktrace in the console. Hunting for errors eats up a lot more time. How can I get the info I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Tools* > *Preferences* > *Run and Debug* you can change the policy for *Breaking on exceptions*. By selecting *all* the editor will break on every exceptions and you will be able to see stacktraces in the debugger panel.

Comment: It's already set to "uncaught", I tried "all" and it still doesn't show me anything.

Comment: Does the program suspend in the _Debugger_ panel ? I just made a simple test in Dart Editor version 0.6.19_r26297 and that works as expected.

Comment: Yeah, I had been using 0.6.15. When I updated my Dart Editor, it worked better. Thanks.